# How to get currently executed Cucumber test scenario title and step text

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Thanks for help in advance.
I'm looking for a way how I can retrieve currently executed test scenario and step from ruby. I've been trying to find a way but been rather unsuccessful.

I know that for most uses it's not very common, but I would like to experiment with few ideas and I really need to get this kind of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Scenario Hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#scenario-hooks) to get steps for each scenario:

```
After do |scenario|
  scenario.steps.each { |s| puts s.to_sexp }
end
```